# Once user reaches a particular point on a page, automatically scroll to particular point/achor

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, here it is:

I'll have 4 divs. Example below. Each div a particular height (around 1500px) but have a width of 100%. Each div is a different colour.

I want it so that when the user scrolls the page and reach a particular point, javascript will kick in and automatically scroll the user to the next div.

So, say the user is vertically scrolling and div #2 is appear and div #1 is disappearing. When div #1 has about 200px left, the page will automatically scroll down so that div #2 is flush with the top of the browser window.

A good example: http://thejuly16.com/ Which basically does it but can't work out how.

---

1

Content here

---

2

Content here

---

3

Content here

---

4

Content here

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page isn't doing anything for me :/

Anyway, if I get what you mean, you should have some anchors on top of every div, hook some code to the scroll event, check `scrollTop()` value on it, and scroll to the anchors when this value is in a desired range. You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmmes/) and the relevant jQuery code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    if (($(window).scrollTop() > 1300) && ($(window).scrollTop() < 1350)) {
        window.scrollTo(0,1500);
    }
});
```

This might be a strange behavior for the user, since scrolling up is pretty messed up. However, we can fix this by checking if the user is going up or down in the page, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmmes/1/), just checking if the last scroll position was higher or lower than the current scroll position:

```
var currentScroll = 0;
var previousScroll = 0;

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (($(window).scrollTop() > 1300) && ($(window).scrollTop() < 1350) && currentScroll > previousScroll) {
        window.scrollTo(0,1500);
    }
    previousScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

Obviously, you'd need to add as many if statements as "jumps" you want in your page.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! This is brilliant. You may be able to help me out a bit further because most of that went over my head. How to I add more Divs? If I add a third div it doesn't work. How can I make it smoothly scroll to that point rather then jumping? Is it also possible to make it only scroll if the user's scroll is idled? And when I scroll up, say 10 px, it doesn't begin scrolling back down to that point? Is any of these things possible? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution as given in the code below. Somehow its not working on jsFiddle but working on my machine. Please try it in your own editor

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var isWorking = false;
var lastScrollPosition
function adjust(oDiv) {
    if(oDiv.scrollTop > lastScrollPosition && !isWorking && oDiv.scrollTop % 400 > 300) {
        isWorking = true
        scroll(oDiv);
    } else
        lastScrollPosition = oDiv.scrollTop;
}

function scroll(div) {
    if(div.scrollTop % 400 > 10) {
        div.scrollTop = div.scrollTop + 10;
        lastScrollPosition = div.scrollTop;
        setTimeout(function(){scroll(div);}, 10);
    } else
        isWorking = false;
}
  </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <div style="height: 440px; border: solid 1px red; overflow-Y: auto" onscroll="adjust(this)">
    <div style="height: 400px; border: solid 1px green"></div>
    <div style="height: 400px; border: solid 1px green"></div>
    <div style="height: 400px; border: solid 1px green"></div>
    <div style="height: 400px; border: solid 1px green"></div>
    <div style="height: 100px"></div>
</div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks heaps for your help. I appreciate it. I'm having a bit of a problem with this. I want the scrolling to occur only when the user has stopped scrolling. And once they reach that point and scroll upwards a small amount, it begins to scroll back to that point. Its weird scrolling to the bottom of the page because it jumps a lot. But its a really good code and I really like it. Thanks heaps for your help and any further help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this functionality is available with jQuery. I have tried this but I was doing this on OnClick event in Javascript. In your case, onFocus or any other suitable event like mouseover etc should work.

Hope this helps.